# Highcharts Angular date on x-axis is different

Tags: angular, highcharts

We are developing a dashboard for one of our customer and the data that we are receiving for graphing is from one of the controller on site.
We are using Highcharts Stock to visualize the data and using Cumulocity as a tool for the project in which we are using Angular for making this dashboard.
While inserting the data (Time series Data) through Json API the date time is not rendering the correct value that we are using and it’s showing date of 2024.

[image]

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

 

import * as Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";
import { Options } from "highcharts/highstock";

 

// For demonstration purposes only.
import random from "highcharts-random";

 

import { HttpRequestService } from './highchart-widget.service';

 

@Component({
  template: `<highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" style="width: 750px; height: 400px; display: block;"
            [constructorType]="'stockChart'" [options]="chartOptions">`,
  styleUrls: ['./highchart-widget.component.css']
})
export class HighchartWidget {

 

  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;

 

  constructor(public httpRequestService: HttpRequestService) {  }

 

  chartOptions: Options = {
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        dataGrouping: {
          enabled: false,
          forced: false,
          units: [["day", [1]]]
        }
      }
    },
    scrollbar: {
      enabled: true
    },
    navigator: {
      enabled: true
    },
    yAxis: {
      min:-4,
      max:70,
      gridLineWidth: 1,
      title: {
        text: "SULFOX 2 plus - FF",
        //textAlign : 'center',
        style: { color: "purple", fontSize: "10px" }
      },

 

      plotLines: [
        {
          value: 50,
          color: "red",
          dashStyle: 'Dash',
          width: 2,
          label: {
            text: "HH"
          }
        },
        {
          value: 25,
          color: "yellow",
          dashStyle: 'Dash',
          width: 1.5,
          label: {
            text: "H"
          }
        },
        {
          value: -1,
          color: "yellow",
          dashStyle: 'Dash',
          width: 1.5,
          label: {
            text: "L"
          }
        },
        {
          value: -2,
          color: "red",
          dashStyle: 'Dash',
          width: 1.5,
          label: {
            text: "LL"
          }
        }
      ]
    },

 

    series: [
      {
        type: "line",
        pointInterval: 3600 * 1000,
        data: this.ffChartData,
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2021, 4, 4)
      }
    ]
  };

 

}
```

Comment: Hi @Saif Hassan, Could you provide me with a sample of your data? I mean the `this.ffChartData` value.

Comment: "values": {
        "2021-02-07T02:02:00.000Z": [
            {
                "min": 2256.11,
                "max": 2256.11
            }
        ],
        "2021-02-07T06:17:00.000Z": [
            {
                "min": 2288.07,
                "max": 2288.07
            }
        ],
        "2021-02-07T10:32:00.000Z": [
            {
                "min": 2300.65,
                "max": 2300.65
            }...
This Kind of JSON API I'm getting

Comment: Ok, but do you convert them somehow? There are not in a valid data structure. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qs3t6nbx/

Comment: That I need to understand how to parse my data to a valid data.

Comment: Here I'm only inserting the data value not the timestamp

Comment: this.ffChartData = [1919.09, 1801.36, 1734.72, 1721.16, 1709.81, 1716.77, 1715.69, 1724.09, 1736.71, 1737.89, 1745.45, 1740.38, 1722.61, 1693.6, 1665.32, 1664.18, 1632, 1611.03, 1584, 1545.63, 1526.88, 1505.96, 1466.46, 1460.75, 1442.98, 1411.25, 1402.88, 1363.01, 1350.7, 1334.8, 1274.4, 1243.38, 1231.97, 1199.96, 1164.58, 1165.27, 1123.09, 1109.27, 1094.71, 1061.64, 1041.69, 1016.69, 970.25, 947.27, 923.33, 898.69, 871.57, 838.96, 817.65, 796.19, 774.41, 750.13, 723, 684.21, 659.16, 634.6, 606.62, 578.03, 550.73, 508.86, 483.4, 456.79, 433.42, 422.14, 402.64, 397.73, 397.91, 399.18, 398.62]

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your data to the format required by Highcharts: `[x, y]` where `x` is a timestamp in milliseconds.

```
const ffChartData = {
    "2021-02-07T02:02:00.000Z": [{
        "min": 2256.11,
        "max": 2256.11
    }],
    "2021-02-07T06:17:00.000Z": [{
        "min": 2288.07,
        "max": 2288.07
    }],
    "2021-02-07T10:32:00.000Z": [{
        "min": 2300.65,
        "max": 2300.65
    }]
}

const processedData = [];

for (const date in ffChartData) {
    processedData.push([new Date(date).getTime(), ffChartData[date].max]);
}

Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    ...
    series: [{
        data: processedData,
        ...
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qew0t184/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.data